# Can't send PATCH request to Vimeo API

Tags: postman, vimeo-api

I am trying to send a PATCH request to the Vimeo API in order to start uploading the video based on the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach-step-2).

I am using Postman. I've read {upload.upload_link} field, set the required headers but I still can't hit the API.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What does the Vimeo API return when you attempt the PATCH request? How large is video.mp4?

Comment: @TommyPenner I only get "Could not get any response, There was an error connecting to https://files.tus.vimeo.com/files/.......". The video is about 8Mb

Answer (score 0):

Try making that PATCH request again, but without the Authorization or Host headers, as they are not required for that upload endpoint:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach-step-2

Comment: I did it and I got the same result.

Comment: I can send you the postman collection if you think you could help.